# Codeigniter ci_session cookie (GDPR problem)

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, session-cookies, data-protection

I have a site written in CodeIgniter which, by default, creates ci_session cookie when first visiting the website. The client requests to make the site GDPR-compliant. I did not add any cookies or local storage beside the google analytics. I do add some stuff to php session variable, but I recon it does not fall under the GDPR scope.

So, basically I have following cookies on the site load:

- ci_session
- google analytics cookies

I already have an idea how to deal with google analytics cookies, but ci_session baffles me. As I understand, on the first page load, absolutely no cookies are allowed before clients consent.

My question is: "What would be the best way to disable the ci_session cookie before a user gave the consent?"

*Codeigniter version 2.1.7

Comment: do you autoload the session library ?

Comment: It is not in the autoload config file, but I do load it in constructor of the authentication library that is autoloaded. I could put the check there and if true - load the library.

Comment: yeah - the only thing i would do - is to check if the consent was made (once the user did that - you should set a cookie and access it in your Authentication library - if it is set - just load the session library)

Comment: But, by not loading session library, I will also not get the server-side session handling, which is very important for the site.
Maybe to tweak the session library it self?

Comment: i wouldn't fiddle with the session library. Instead, tweak the constructor to not load the session library on your landing page until the user has given consent. Since it's a landing page, there's really not much benefit from loading the session library upon first visit.

Comment: It is a webshop and I have designed it to be able to buy stuff right from the landing page (and it keeps some of the important information in server-side session).

Comment: as long as i don't gv my consent - you shouldnt store any things - so the session library should be obsolete.. (no idea which data you store in a session if the user is unknown...), I've also no idea whats your definition here - can i still buy products (or store them in a cart) even if i don't gv my consent ?

Comment: there's a lot of discussion around this whole GDPR cookie consenting. CI session cookies store only an internal identifier (not "trackable" information) on the user's end and could be deemed "essential" for the site's functioning so unconsenting users should be barred from even entering the site until they consent. If you need to be able to sell right from the landing page, thus requiring the session library to load on the landing page, you should tweak that (and not the session itself) to only allow purchasing for consenting users

Comment: I thought about using server-side session for the information if the user consented to using cookies/local storage or not.
I am not all clear on the way how it should be implemented. I was thinking of yes/no buttons, which via ajax call store the decision into server-side session attribute (as well as in local storage). Is there a better way?

Comment: I failed to see use of cookies in a way to access them server side before the page load. Will try that than.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curious as it may seem, GDPR says nothing about cookies except a mention in a recital (background info, not law) relating to persistent identifiers. What *is* applicable is the EU electronic privacy directive, which will eventually be replaced by the electronic privacy regulation ("ePR"). The [UK ICO's guidance on cookies](https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/guide-to-pecr/cookies-and-similar-technologies/#exemptions) under ePD says:

> There is an exemption if:
>
> the cookie is for the sole purpose of carrying out the transmission of a communication over an electronic communications network; or
>
> the cookie is strictly necessary to provide an ‘information society service’ (eg a service over the internet) requested by the subscriber or user. Note that it must be essential to fulfil their request – cookies that are helpful or convenient but not essential, or that are only essential for your own purposes, will still require consent.
>
> This means you are unlikely to need consent for:
>
> cookies used to remember the goods a user wishes to buy when they add goods to their online basket or proceed to the checkout on an internet shopping website;
>
> session cookies providing security that is essential to comply with data protection security requirements for an online service the user has requested – eg online banking services; or
>
> load-balancing cookies that ensure the content of your page loads quickly and effectively by distributing the workload across several computers.

Note that Google Analytics does not qualify as strictly necessary under this definition; it's not just about cookies though - what is meant to be prevented is *tracking without consent*, of which cookies are but one means of implementing that, and loading a javascript from google is indeed tracking, even if they do not set cookies (which GA can be set to do).

While cookies should not be set at all on the initial visit, prior to any opportunity for consent, first-party session cookies for authentication *definitely* qualify as "strictly necessary" for technical purposes and thus do not require consent in the first place. Session cookies (by definition) are deleted when a window is closed anyway, but you can pre-empt even that by also setting a [Clear-Site-Data header](https://www.w3.org/TR/clear-site-data/) on logout.

With reference to how CodeIgniter handles this, I'd say it's worth a bug report *or* avoid calling anything that will cause a session to be started prior to login.